# php, mysql- join three tables in mysql under some special cases

Tags: php, mysql

tbl_person

```
id bank_id address
1   100     null
2   100     null
3   100     null
```

tbl_bank

```
id address_id balance
100      2      500
```

tbl_address

```
id  address_id  address
1    2           texas
2    2            ny
3    2          downtown
```

I wanted an output like this

```
   id  bank_id   address
    1   100        texas
    2   100        ny
    3   100       downtown
```

I tried  this query, but it results 9 rows as expected. can anyone help to get the desired output. No rows will get deleted

```
SELECT tp.id, tp.bank_id,ta.address  
FROM `tbl_person`as tp 
    join tbl_bank as tb on tp.`bank_id`=tb.id 
    join tbl_address as ta on ta.address_id=tb.address_id 
WHERE tp.`bank_id`=100
```

```
   id  bank_id   address
    1   100        texas
    2   100        texas
    3   100       texas
    1   100        ny
    2   100        ny
    3   100       ny
    1   100        downtown
    2   100        downtown
    3   100       downtown
```

Is there a way to get the result(3 rows) using join  or any other method in php?

Comment: You might want to rethink that database design

Comment: yes. the db design is not correct. can you make query with existing table structure? I know its weird.

Comment: What relation between tbl_person to tbl_address? It's not clear :(

Comment: Actually there is no relation between tbl_person & tbl_address. thats why its a weird condition. Theres relation between  tbl_person & tbl_bank,  and  tbl_bank & tbl_address.

Comment: is your `tbl_address` data correct? It seems odd that each of those rows have the same `address_id`, which is where the duplicate rows are coming from. If these were unique then your query would work.

Comment: in tbl_address, address_id is not  unique. it would be like as  given in the table

Comment: It is appearing duplicate because of the redundant bank_id  in tbl_person.